# Prevent Review Queue Flooding

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, serial-edits

Every so often, you get someone who makes hundreds of edits in a day. That's not a problem, is it? It is when their only edit is correcting a spelling error for ***one word***!

This is a problem because they can make all these edits, and then roughly half will be approved! This is gaming the review system. It's a problem!

With the 20 reviews per UTC day, you get good reviewers who reject them, but then the reviewer loses the ability to review until the next UTC day! You then get some bad reviewer who just clicks through them all (even *with* the audit).

Why are we only allowed to make 5 edits to our posts per day while you can make *unlimited* edits to other's posts? It surely should be the other way around. How can we prevent gaming the system? Should we add some flood detection system?

Comment: There's a limit to how many times we can edit our *own* posts?

Comment: That was likely about the 20 review limit.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I do believe there is, to prevent users from vandalizing their own posts and "ragequitting". Or it might have been something else, like deleting or something. We could always try... quick edit a ton of your posts and see what happens!

Comment: @animuson hmph! Maybe I will!

Comment: Were you thinking a limit of X suggested edits per day, or X *pending* suggested edits per day?  I'm more inclined to go with the later, depending on what X is set to (if it's the later it could be quite low, like 5, if it's the former it'd need to be...more).

Comment: The limit on editing your own posts is 5 per day according to the [Rate Lmiting FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/182513).  But I thought there was one for regular edits too... I guess not

Comment: @psubsee2003 good find. It does say it scales up per rep, too. Wonder how much!

Comment: Can we get a status tag on this?

Comment: I could have sworn that there were days where I've edited way more than 5 of my own posts.

Comment: @SamIam Areyou sure you did more than 5 in a _UTC_ day? The counter resets at 0:00 UTC.

Answer (score 13):

The main thing that I'm seeing here that concerns me is users who suggest a mass number of edits which are then exempt from a potential edit ban if they were bad. So my suggestion is users shouldn't be able to have more than five pending suggestions at a single time. That way if all five were to get rejected, the edit ban would prevent them from flooding the system with more. It would also dramatically slow down those users who *are* just going post-by-post fixing a single letter, and maybe make them rethink their strategy.

Aside from that, I'm not really concerned with users making large numbers of edits in a single day. There's no real way to determine if the edits are bad in nature and prevent them; that's what reviewers are for, and if they're actually approving them then we should be finding better ways of dealing with *that* rather than the one suggesting. We certainly don't want to be putting inhibitors on those who are actually making *good* edits, though.

Comment: But they change just ONE typo, even if it exists more than once, or there are more problems with the post...

Comment: @ColeJohnson its ok to "improve" reviews and its fine to leave a comment when you reject edits.

Comment: `It would also dramatically slow down those users who are just going post-by-post fixing a single letter, and maybe make them rethink their strategy.`  I though the same thing, but then I remembered that pending edits sit in the queue for a grand total of 30 seconds before being approved, and I realized it wouldn't be that much of a hindrance.  It's still likely to help a bit though.

Comment: Wouldn't this also stop the people who make 100 good edits in a day? I like the idea but I think we only want to hinder the bad people. Maybe, automagically remove all pending edits if someone gets banned?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best action for this problem is "DO NOT TAKE ANY ACTION".

The rationale for limiting the editing of own posts to a maximum of five in a day is to prevent rage-quitting and flooding the front page in order to attract votes. This is because our own edits do not have to go through a review process. (However, my understanding is that the system automatically generates flags for moderators and high-reputation-points users if a couple of own posts are edited in a short span of time - this should also apply for a couple of edits to posts done by 2000+ users in a short span of time to other user's post).

Since, edits by users having less than 2000 reputation points have to go through the process of revie. It's assumed that only good edits would ultimately be approved and others get rejected. This is what generally happens, barring a few!!

If we were to apply [the suggestion of maximum of five pending suggestions at a given time - by @animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172755/205516), this would further worsen the situation. The users who suggest good edits would not be able to do so.

I would give my example, in my typical workflow - suppose I browse the site at a stretch of 30 mins, I come and watch a couple of questions/answers, I edit the ones if I can improve the post and move on. I can very easily exceed the limit of five. I can remember more than a few occasions when more than 8-10 edit suggestions of mine were pending in queue at a given time. Once I had 18-19 edit suggestions pending at a time on [Ask Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ask_Ubuntu)!!! It can take 2-3 hours for an edit to be reviewed.

So, you review those one word improvements and reject the ones which should be rejected. You have played your part and give others the chance to take up further review of posts.

And the system automatically generates flags if it notices a couple of edits by a user in a short span of time. So, there already is a sort of flood detection system running.